# Save the highscore time

Tags: swift, time, label

Save Sorry for my english, but i am just programming a game and try the time when the time is better than high score in a new label as high scores.
My code for the time of each new game. This also works.

```
let labelText = NSString(format: "Zeit: %.2f Sekunden", Float(endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)))
        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 50))
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 25)
        label.text = labelText
        label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.frame.size.height*0.9 - 50)
        label.tag = LABEL_TAG
        view.addSubview(label)
```

And this is my code for the high score and now I do not know how to save the time in this label like this is better than the previous one. Now this label is always the same time as just earned.

```
let labelText2 = NSString(format: "Highscore: %.2f Sekunden", Float(endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)))
        highScoreLableInApp.text = labelText2
        highScoreLableInApp.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 25)
        highScoreLableInApp.textAlignment = .Center
        highScoreLableInApp.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.frame.size.height*0.9 - 15)
        highScoreLableInApp.tag = LABEL_TAG3
        println("Highscore ist geladen")
        view.addSubview(highScoreLableInApp)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Aufgrund deiner Texte, nehme ich an du spricht deutsch. 

 Eine Möglichkeit wäre über

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
```

den Highscore global zu setzen. Der Highscore bleibt dann auch bei einem Neustart vorhanden.

 Dann kannst du mit

```
NSUserDefaults.getObjectForKey("highscore")
```

den aktuellen Highscore laden und verarbeiten.